# Выделение памяти С++

Tags: память, c++

Вопрос достаточно простой, но для меня он неясен.
Всем известно, что в С++ у нас есть несколько способов выделения памяти.
В моем случае у нас есть главный объект приложения. В нем создаются главные части: объект ядра и объект интерфейса. Мой вопрос состоит в следующем. Каким образом лучше выделять память под эти объекты.
1 вариант:

```
GlCore gl_core;
Gui gui;
```

2 вариант:

```
GlCore *gl_core;
Gui *gui;
```

В первом случае я вижу плюсы в том, что не нужно думать о `delete` и в том, что память выделиться на этапе запуска приложения. Но я использую `wxwidgets` и там элементы интерфейса советуют создавать по второму варианту. Оно ясно, что это чем-то обусловлено, но я к сожалению не могу понять и сделать для себя какой-то вывод. Мне интересны обоснованные плюсы в пользу того или иного варианта выделения памяти.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не должны думать о мелких несущественных технических деталях, наподобие «нужно вызывать `delete` или сэкономим одну строчку». Не экономьте на спичках. Думайте о смысле.

Нужны ли вам объекты `gl_core` и `gui` всегда, или вы хотите создать их в какой-то определённый, контролируемый вами момент? Требуют ли они, чтобы что-то было инициализировано до их создания? Если да, глобальный объект — не лучшее место.

Требуют ли объекты `gl_core` и `gui` подчистить за собой, когда они больше не нужны (например, когда приложение завершает работу графической части)? Если да, вам неплохо бы вызвать деструктор (посредством `delete`) вручную, а не дожидаться автоматической деаллокации в конце жизни приложения.

Comment: То есть по-хорошему, если я хочу достигнуть модульности, то лучше всего работать через указатели, потому что в таком случае, модулями будет прощу манипулировать. Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @shestakov, а если вместо указателей создавать объект на стеке, передавая указатели на него ниже по иерархии вызовов?